# How to updating an exising netCDF array in python

Tags: python, arrays, netcdf

I have a code as shown below, I want to update the existing NetCDF file according to another NetCDF file. If in the other NetCDF file `value=0` at the place of the existing NetCDF file then it is 0. So I only consider the place where the other netcdf not equal to 0

```
import netCDF4 as net

days=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
months=["02","03","04","05","06","07"]

for month in months:
    for day in days:
        try:
            infile=net.Dataset("2015%s%s-160000_0.nc" % (month,day),"w")
            value=infile.variables['HailProb'][:]
            value1=infile1.variables['hailsie'][:]
            infile[value==0 or value1==0]==0
            infile.close()
        except RuntimeError:
            continue
```

Because if I open the `infile` in write mode I worry all the existing data would be rewritten. Can somebody take a look at how I address the issue here? Whats wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in append mode with `a`:

```
infile=net.Dataset("2015%s%s-160000_0.nc" % (month,day), "a")
```

Now you can read and write to an existing file as the docs say:

> `a` and `r+` mean append (in analogy with
>   serial files); an existing file is opened for reading and writing.

Comment: isnt it append mode only append from the end of the arrary instead of updating?

Comment: Now the problem is that     infile[value==0 or value1==0]==0 is wrong it gives me error

Comment: What do you want achieve with `infile[value==0 or value1==0]==0`.  You cannot use `[]` with a file object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there were a couple of problems with your code.

1. In order to change an existing file, I think you should read it in `r+` (or, as mentioned by Mike Müller, in `a`) mode.
2. With `infile[value==0 or value1==0]==0`, `infile` is not your data array, but the `netCDF4` object. To change the variable, you need something like `infile.variables["HailProb"]...`
3. With `infile[..]==0`, `==` tests for equality, it doesn't set a new value in `infile` (use `=` for that, if `infile` was actually an array)
4. Your line with `value==0 or value1==0` won't work; you need something like `(value==0) | (value1==0)` to slice the array.

I think that something like this should work:

```
import netCDF4 as net

days=["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]
months=["02","03","04","05","06","07"]

for month in months:
    for day in days:
        try:
            infile = net.Dataset("2015%s%s-160000_0.nc" % (month,day), "r+")
            value  = infile.variables['HailProb'][:]
            value1 = infile1.variables['hailsie'][:]
            infile.variables['HailProb'][(value==0) | (value1==0)] = 0
            infile.close()
        except RuntimeError:
            continue
```

A more complete working example, which also creates the NetCDF files to play around with:

```
import netCDF4 as nc4
import numpy as np

# Create NetCDF file 1
nc1  = nc4.Dataset('nc1.nc', 'w')
nc1.createDimension('z', 10)
nc_var = nc1.createVariable('HailProb', 'f8', 'z')

# Add some dummy data, and set a single value to zero:
nc_var[:] = np.random.randint(2, 10, size=10)
nc_var[5] = 0
nc1.close()

# Create NetCDF file 2
nc2  = nc4.Dataset('nc2.nc', 'w')
nc2.createDimension('z', 10)
nc_var = nc2.createVariable('hailsie', 'f8', 'z')

# Add some dummy data, and set a single value to zero:
nc_var[:] = np.random.randint(2, 10, size=10)
nc_var[3] = 0
nc2.close()

# Read files back
# File 1 in in "r+" mode, since we want to edit it
nc1 = nc4.Dataset('nc1.nc', 'r+')
value = nc1.variables["HailProb"][:]

# File 2 only required "r" (read) mode
nc2 = nc4.Dataset('nc2.nc', 'r')
value1 = nc2.variables["hailsie"][:]

# Update NetCDF file based on some conditions
nc1.variables["HailProb"][(value==0) | (value1==0)] = 0

nc1.close()
nc2.close()
```

After running the first part of the code (creation of `nc1.nc` and `nc2.nc`), `ncdump -v HailProp nc1.nc` and `ncdump -v hailcie nc2.nc` gives me:

```
HailProb = 2, 9, 6, 6, 9, 0, 5, 4, 8, 6 ;
hailsie  = 4, 6, 2, 0, 4, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7 ;
```

After running the second part of the code, I get:

```
HailProb = 5, 6, 8, 0, 7, 0, 6, 4, 2, 4 ;
```

Comment: [(value==0) | (value1==0)]  isnit is the bar meaning and? but i actually want a or

Comment: No,  `&` means _and_, `|` is _or_. See e.g. [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) documentation

Comment: `numpy` also has built-in operators for this, so something like `nc1.variables["HailProb"][np.logical_or(value==0, value1==0)] = 0` should also work

Comment: I tried exactly i like said. the file does not being updated at all. its still the same file, i can see the date of the infile does not change.

Comment: Can you update your post and add the code that you are trying now? Otherwise we can only guess what is going wrong